# Adding Spring <%@taglib%> to JSPX file causes: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: spring, jsp, jspx

I am using Springframework 4.0.3 implement my web-app and I see this exception when I try to access my jsp, however I see other people use in this way without problem.

My jsp code as below and it says exception happening on line2 column2, please help.

```
<jsp:directive.page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<html>
.....
</html>
```

Comment: try placing this above `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Comment: This is a mix of XML and classic directives, never did combine them, see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_directives.htm - is the file type .xhtml (XML?). Maybe they disabled the XML validation.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks, after I change first line to classic directives, it gives same exception but this time on line1

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone The same result by adding this on top

Comment: That means plain XML validation is done, as `<@...>` is not XML complieant; the other people probably do not have this enabled. Maybe something with file extension association, in your IDE.

Comment: what is the file extension of your "jsp code" ?? `.jsp` or `.jspx` ? and where do you see the exception? in the IDE diagnostics or on the deployment (say, in browser/server console logs)?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try adding this to your top of jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: The same result after adding this.

Answer (score -1):

It may helps you :

replace your code :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
```

with

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="spring"%>
```

Comment: are you include the jar file of spring?

Comment: can you be more detail on spring jar incluing?

Comment: Add spring-webmvc.jar file in your classpath.